# cakephp saveMany not saving the records in Table

Tags: cakephp

Here is my code

```
$users = array( 
                    array( 'username' => $this->request->data['Shop']['admin_username'],
                           'password' => $this->request->data['Shop']['admin_password'],
                           'role' => 'admin',
                           'shop_id' => $shop_id,
                           'active' => 1
                        ),
                    array( 'username' => $this->request->data['Shop']['manager_username'],
                           'password' => $this->request->data['Shop']['manager_password'],
                           'role' => 'manager',
                           'shop_id' => $shop_id,
                           'active' => 1
                        )

                );

                Debugger::dump($users); 

                //$this->User->create();
                $this->User->saveMany($users);
```

where I am trying to save the 2 recoded in Database. But it's not working. I have also tried saveAll but i also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

What does `$this->User->saveMany($users);` return?

Are there any validation rules you have inside your User Model?